# Android actionview overflow icon

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar

I am trying to add overflow icon (three dots) as actionview (for animation). However the click listener for overflow icon is not working. I want to show the overflow when clicked on actionview.

Edit:

Following sample Code I am using:

[Github](https://gist.github.com/bangarharshit/0e142b6d2faac73c397a)

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.fragment_chatlist, menu);
}

@Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    inboxMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search);
    inboxMenuItem.setActionView(R.layout.menu_item_chatlist);
    settingsMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.mainMenu);
    settingsMenuItem.setActionView(R.layout.menu_item_settings);
    if (null != animationWatcher && animationWatcher.getPendingAnimation() == true) {
        animationWatcher.upatePendingAnimation(false);
        startIntroAnimation();
    }
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) inboxMenuItem.getActionView();
    searchView.setOnSearchClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ((ChatListActivity) getActivity()).setLogoVisibility(false);
        }
    });

    searchView.setOnCloseListener(new SearchView.OnCloseListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onClose() {
            ((ChatListActivity) getActivity()).setLogoVisibility(true);
            return false;
        }
    });

    settingsMenuItem.getActionView().setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ChatList.this.onOptionsItemSelected(settingsMenuItem);
            ((ChatListActivity) (getActivity())).toolbar.showOverflowMenu();
            ((ChatListActivity) (getActivity())).openOptionsMenu();
        }
    });
}
```

[For Menu](https://gist.github.com/bangarharshit/2bd1546942d491e5e7ce)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_search"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/search"
        />


    <item
        android:id="@+id/mainMenu"
        android:title="Text"
        android:orderInCategory="101"
        app:showAsAction="always">
        <menu>

            <item
                android:id="@+id/menu_tag"
                android:icon="@drawable/tag_icon"
                app:showAsAction="always|withText"
                android:title="Tags"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/menu_profile"
                android:icon="@drawable/profile_image_50"
                app:showAsAction="always|withText"
                android:title="Profile"/>
        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

ActionView is a searchview and imagebutton respectively.

The thing is I want to open actionview

Comment: share the code what you did

Comment: show some codes where you have implemented the click listener for your overflow icon..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by a hack. Set actionview to null after animation completes.